# UFT-Object Repository

Tags: hp-uft

I have added few objects from my application and ran the script which worked well. But when I close and open my application, the OR not identifying the properties. If I update it again it works. Can anyone suggest a solution for this?. My application is windows application which directs to server

Comment: Please provide more details and a minimal example reproducing your issue

Comment: Try and compare the properties before and after updating the OR. Can you figure out what property is changing ?

Comment: It seems U have dynamic object. For example title of ur window or any other property changes every time u re-lauch app. Look for dynamic property for the object and add regular expression or parameterize it as per nature of your app.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you did save the object repository file after updating it.

As it's window based app, static fields are unlikely to change. You need to elaborate more on this.

If you see that the dynamic values are changing you can follow the below approach.
It may be possible that the properties are changing in real time and hence UFT is failing to recognize it. To test this, you can use GetROProperty and compare it with the values in OR. If it's different you know what to do :)